# test class for a try catch block

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

There is a class in which i am using a `try catch block` which catch exception based on `permissionset given to the user`.

Something like this -

```
public pageReference backtomainpage(){
    try{
       PermissionSet PS=[Select p.Name, p.Id From PermissionSet p where p.Name='abc' limit 1];

       PermissionSetAssignment PSA=[Select PermissionSetId, Id, AssigneeId From PermissionSetAssignment where PermissionSetId=:PS.Id and AssigneeId=:UserInfo.getUserId()];

       pageReference pg = new pageReference('/apex/page1'+currentOpp.id);
       pg.setRedirect(true);  
       return pg;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        pageReference pg = new pageReference('/apex/page2+currentOpp.id);
        pg.setRedirect(true);
        return pg;     
    }   
}
```

I have to write a `test class` for this. So for this , my approach is to create 2 users and a permission set 'xyz' in test class and provide 'abc' permissionset to one and 'xyz' to 2nd one.
But I am not able to find a way to add permissionset to a user in test class. 
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public static User getUserWithSpecifiedPermSet(Set<String> permSetNames) {

    User u                      = new User();
    u.Username                  = 'test@test.com';
    u.Email                     = 'test@test.com';
    u.Lastname                  = 'user';
    u.Firstname                 = 'test';
    u.Alias                     = 'test';
    u.ProfileId                 = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'profile name'].Id;
    u.TimeZoneSidKey            = 'GMT';
    u.LocaleSidKey              = 'en_US';
    u.EmailEncodingKey          = 'ISO-8859-1';
    u.LanguageLocaleKey         = 'en_US';
    u.UserPermissionsMobileUser = false;
    insert u;

    List<PermissionSetAssignment> psas = new List<PermissionSetAssignment>();
    for (PermissionSet ps : [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE Name = :permSetNames]) {
        psas.add(new PermissionSetAssignment(AssigneeId = u.Id, PermissionSetId = ps.Id));
    }
    insert psas;
    return u;
}
```